# Firebase dynamic links deprecated Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, dynamic-links

***Deprecated: Firebase Dynamic Links is deprecated and should not be adopted in projects that don't already use it. The service will shut down on August 25, 2025. See the Dynamic Links Deprecation FAQ for more information.***

Firebase is going to deprecate the firebase_dynamic_links so the recommended way in flutter is https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation/deep-linking

So I followed this documentation and everything is working fine

```xml
<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="somedomain.fr" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

I am working in news based application and I want to share the news article

I don't know how to hide the sensitive data in the link

For Example `https://somedomain.fr/articles?id=10`

I would like to share link with some encrypted format. Is there any way to do this?